# Sorting of d'n'd'ed list items in multiple lists by list-specific item's field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, drag-and-drop, angulardraganddroplists

The app (AngularJS 1.5.11, https://codepen.io/loenko/pen/qPOWRp) is the group of lists with draggable items (implemented with dnd-list directive from corresponding package https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists).

Items in all the three lists are from the same array of item objects. They are put into the corresponding list by filter on item's 'list' property.

**The problem is** in sorting of items inside of lists after dragging and dropping of the item. They should be (I want them to be) placed exactly where they're dropped, but they're sorted automatically (dropped item is pushed to the end of the list).

**Is there a way to implement such functionality without creating any additional sorting arrays, changing the d'n'd implementation package and changing the data model (it's predefined)?**

*Anyway, I'll appreciate all the alternative solutions!*

The structure of lists is as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="list in lists">
        <ul dnd-list="list" 
            dnd-drop="callback({targetName: list.name})">
            <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:item.list=list.name" 
                dnd-draggable="item"
                dnd-callback="item.list = targetName">
                {{item.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

The data model is:

```
$scope.lists=[
        {name:"List 1"}, {name:"List 2"}, {name:"List 3"}
    ];
$scope.items=[
        {name:"Item 1",list:"List 1"}, {name:"Item 2",list:"List 2"}, {name:"Item 3",list:"List 3"}
    ];
```

```js
angular.module('app', ['dndLists'])
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
 $scope.lists=[
  {name:"List 1"}, {name:"List 2"}, {name:"List 3"}
 ];
 $scope.items=[
  {name:"Item 1",list:"List 1"},{name:"Item 2",list:"List 2"},{name:"Item 3",list:"List 3"}
 ];
 $scope.addItem = function() {
  var newItemIndex = $scope.items.length+1;
  var newItemName = prompt("Enter new item name", "Item "+newItemIndex);
  if (newItemName == null || newItemName == "") {
   console.log("User cancelled the prompt.");
  } else {
   $scope.items.push({name:newItemName,list:"List 2"});
  }
 };
 $scope.clear = function() {
  var confClear = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete all the items?")
  if (confClear = true) $scope.items = [];
 }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.toolbar {
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgray;
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.toolbar button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 160px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px green;
  outline-style: none;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}
.toolbar button:hover {
  background-color: #64e764;
}

ul[dnd-list] {
  min-height: 40px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid lightgray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 70%;
}
ul[dnd-list] .dndDraggingSource {
  display: none;
}
ul[dnd-list] .dndDragging {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
ul[dnd-list] .dndPlaceholder {
  min-height: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px dotted gray;
}

.list {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.item {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.item .item-name {
  line-height: 1.9;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.list-name {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sorting items in lists (d'n'd issue)</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
 <div class="toolbar">
  <button ng-click="addItem()">ADD ITEM</button>
  <button ng-click="clear()">CLEAR LIST</button></div>
 <div class="list" ng-repeat="list in lists">
  <div class="list-name">{{list.name}}</div>
  <ul dnd-list="list" 
    dnd-drop="callback({targetName: list.name})">
   <li class="item" 
     ng-repeat="item in items | filter:item.list=list.name" 
     dnd-draggable="item"
     dnd-callback="item.list = targetName">
    <div class="item-name">{{item.name}}</div>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/2.1.0/angular-drag-and-drop-lists.min.js'></script>

    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I know this is not exactly what you asked but I played around with your code and if you're happy with some changes like code adjustments and example combined your 2 lists in JSON like this:

```
[
        {
            name: "Test List One",
            items: [
                {
                    name: 'Some item 1',
                    value: 1000
                },
                {
                    name: 'Some item 2',
                    value: 2000
                },
            ]
        },
      {
            name: "Test List Two",
            items: [
                {
                    name: 'Some item 3',
                    value: 3000
                },
                {
                    name: 'Some item 4',
                    value: 4000
                },
            ]
        }
    ];
```

take a look here, https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WZQbPm?editors=1010
I also added some helper functions as well if you need to get some items from new JSON structure.

Sorry if this is not what you asked, but personally I think JSON changes are better also it's bit nicer to write code in functions and expose them to $scope then to write $scope.someFunction every time.

Comment: Thank you, this would be the most convenient and useful step, but the data for original application ($scope.items) are passed from backend in JSON, so, as I said, I cannot change the model, I'm only allowed to work this issue around with some code tricks.

Comment: Well if you are up for some workarounds you can actually modify your 2 lists and put them in one, check the codepen now it uses your models: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WZQbPm?editors=1010

Comment: The problem is that backend part doesn't (can not) return me such structure so I need to compile the passed data in some _transitional object_ (that was my initial idea - in structure that mirrors one provided by you) and then after changing items sorting I need to recompile it to original source (to save the data on server) - too much action in my opinion. If there would be the way to implement sorting without such multistep exchange - it would be perfect!

Comment: Well transforming json and back is a workaround but it's working good,  and you are not having ten thousands records with tons of properties so it's still very fast. Honestly I tried with two lists and I really don't have time to mess with it, even if I would make it, I wouldn't be happy with it. It's backend job to provide you with good data, since in your case it's not possible you will need to work it out by yourself on frontend. Best I could do is provide you with way to get data back to your lists function transformBackToTwoLists(): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eGZROd?editors=1011

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate what you did with this pen, it's awesome!